# Show actual command being executed by Sitecore Installation Framework

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, web-deploy

In order to help diagnose an issue with Web Deploy and Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF), I would like to see the actual `msdeploy` command being executed by the `WebDeploy` SIF Task, including the parameters used.

Is there a way to see/output this?

Comment: Have you tried turning on Verbose in your install command `Install-SitecoreConfiguration @example -Verbose`?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an option in SIF to make it show the final assembled command that is run for every task.

However if you add -Verbose to the Install-SitecoreConfiguration command you will get some extra diagostics from the msdeploy.exe similar to:

`[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -verb:Sync
[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -Source:Package="C:\temp\xp0\Sitecore.IdentityServer 3.0.0 rev. 00207
(OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip"
[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -Dest:Auto
[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="IIS Web Application Name",Value=XP0.identityserver
[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Security Connection String",Value="Data Source=172.21.232.152;Initial
Catalog=XP0-2501_Core;User ID=securityuser;Password=bjjBgHGThKQE5TTjVaNE"
[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name=CertificateThumbprint,Value=2AA520B7C389FE370C7124AF53BA17F0EEC6792B
[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name=PasswordRecoveryUrl,Value=http://XP0.sc
[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name=AllowedCorsOrigins,Value=http://XP0.sc
[WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name=ClientSecret,Value=8h8loJrrR3CJE16fNTOOGa8hwGl1MVIC3DlZZl7MOep9ENfCKa37PwzHV7veptr9ilD
DPtlzlTwJErXCpNQaildAuRTHoSariKF1`

just before the command is executed.